# why am i not able to write data to firebase after i updated security rules

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I tried updating my firestore security rules to this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /entries/{entry}{
      allow read, create, update, delete, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.user;
//user is a property of every document in my collection which holds the user id of logged user
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that I am able to read, update and delete data but not able to create new documents in this collection..what am i doing wrong?
Edit:

```
  console.log(firebaseApp.auth.currentUser.uid)
  firebaseApp.db.collection("entries").add({
    content: encrypt(entryContent),
    time: entryDate.getTime(),
    user: firebaseApp.auth.currentUser.uid,
  });
```

this is the code which is adding new a new doc..

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't do anything.  They are only meaningful when paired with app code that makes a query. Please edit the question to show the app code that's not working the way you expect.  Since your rules require that a user be signed in, be sure to show the code that proves a user is signed by in by printing the current user's UID just before the document is created, and the error that results from the failure.

Comment: i tried printing the uid of the user just before the id was created...i added that code in the question..it gets printed on console without any error..but new doc is still not created..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resource.data` (in fact, the resource object) represents the database document being accessed.  In a `create` situation, it won't exist yet, so it won't be available to match.  For `create`, you'll need to match on the `request` object, which represents the state of the document AFTER the transaction.

I **strongly** suggest you separate your rules into `read`, `create` etc individually, which will allow you to see what you are creating more easily.

Further, the documentation suggest you do NOT have overlapping rules of `write` with `create, update, delete` - since the former is just shorthand for the latter three.

Answer (score 2):

Your rules require that the existing document data contain a field called "user" to be the same as the user's uid:

```
request.auth.uid == resource.data.user
```

`resource.data` contains the fields of an **existing document** that's being read or written.  Non-existing documents don't have a value for `resource.data`.  So, if you are **creating a new document**, this will always evaluate false.

If you want to allow arbitrary users to create a new document, you should have a create rule that looks like this:

```
allow create: if true;
```

If you want to require that users can only create new document that have a field called "user" with their UID, you should use [`request.resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource) to look at the incoming document data before it's created:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.user == request.auth.uid;
```